# Need help separating two meshes that I accidentally put together

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to blender and following the 2019 donut tutorial by BlenderGuru on youtube and i'm on part 4 modelling where you put icing on your donut. I accidentally duplicated two icing tops and didn't realize it until I almost finished modelling the icing. 
They're stacked together and the one I haven't modeled is sticking out and I can't delete it or move it away. I may have accidentally merged them together somehow?[image: enter image description here[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZzoa.jpg)

Comment: maybe you should include the blend file so people can try to figure out the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the mesh and go into edit mode.
2. Deselect vertices.
3. Hover over the mesh you would like to select and press `L`. This will select only the verteces of the original object.
4. Press `P` and choose `selected`. This will separate the selected verteces.